# jQuery, Toggle within toggle

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create some sort of "spoiler" for a forum. It's pretty simple, though i'm fairly new to jquery. But now i got this problem when placing a toggle div element inside another toggle div element, the 2nd toggle doesn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.head').click(function() {
  $('.body').toggle('slow')
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="head">
Show Content
</div>
<!--1st toggle div-->
 <div class="body" style="display:none;">
  Content
    <div class="head">
     Show Content
    </div>
     <!--2nd toggle div-->
     <div class="body" style="display:none;">
     Content
     </div>
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ufC5B/)

Thanks to everyone that's trying to help :)

EDIT:

Right after i posted i've seen that i was using multiple ID's in the HTML code.
I've changed the div id's to classes, but now when i click to show content1, content2
also shows up. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: 1 problem: `id` attributes should be unique on the page. Another way to say it: you should not do two elements with the `id` "body". Try using "class" for that.

Comment: Already seen it, thank you though. And thanks to Joe aswell.

Comment: Sorry Joe, i can't upvote without having 15 reputation points :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah try this https://jsfiddle.net/ufC5B/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.head').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.body:first').toggle('slow')
  });
});
```

Comment: I got it working now on a simple html page. But on the forum it doesn't work. When pressing the first toggle button, the content slides up and down without stopping. The forum software is vbulletin btw. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @JoeGreen Super Script! The sibling thingy works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Both divs show up because `$('.body')` will match all elements in the DOM that have a class of `body` and perform the function on ALL of them.

To avoid that, use specifically named divs or add another identifier to the elements, like the example below.

```
<div class="head" data-depth="1">
    Show Content 1
</div>
<!--1st toggle div-->
<div class="body" data-depth="1" style="display:none;">
    Content
    <div class="head" data-depth="2">
        Show Content 2
    </div>
    <!--2nd toggle div-->
    <div class="body" data-depth="2" style="display:none;">
        Content
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.head').click(function() {
        var depth = $(this).attr('data-depth');
        $('.body[data-depth=' + depth + ']').toggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate it by classes, and then use some nice jQuery Traversal methods to make it cleaner.

We'll use the .next selector, here's a live jsFiddle.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hx7wd/)

Here's the code I've used to make it work; change head and body to classes instead of ID's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.body').toggle('slow')
  });
});
```